# Ansible combine only combines last item

Tags: python, ansible

I need to accomplish something similar to [Ansible, How to modify a variable during a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882281/ansible-how-to-modify-a-variable-during-a-loop) and [Ansible Loop and Update Dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363779/ansible-loop-and-update-dict), however, I need to be able to combine two dictionaries that contain lists into a single dictionary.  One dictionary is stored in group_vars file and the other in host_vars:

group_vars :

```
access_control:
  - source_address: "10.0.0.1/24"
    description: "Test 1"
  - source_address: "11.0.0.1/24"
    description: "Test 2"
  - source_address: "12.0.0.1/24"
    description: "Test 3"
```

host_vars:

```
access_control_id:
  - access_id: "a01"
  - access_id: "a06"
```

The desired result is that each access_control_id is applied to each of the access_control items:

```
"combined_access_control": [
    {
      "source_address": "10.0.0.1/24"
      "description": "Test 1"
      "access_id": "a01"
    },
    {
      "source_address": "10.0.0.1/24"
      "description": "Test 1"
      "access_id": "a06"
    },
    {
      "source_address": "11.0.0.1/24"
      "description": "Test 2"
      "access_id": "a01"
    },
    {
      "source_address": "11.0.0.1/24"
      "description": "Test 2"
      "access_id": "a06"
    },
    {
      "source_address": "12.0.0.1/24"
      "description": "Test 3"
      "access_id": "a01"
    },
    {
      "source_address": "12.0.0.1/24"
      "description": "Test 3"
      "access_id": "a06"
    },
]
```

I thought that I would be able to use something like this:

```
- name: Combine variables into one dict
  set_fact:
    combined_access_control: "{{ combined_access_control| default ([item.1]) + [ { 'access_id': item.1.access_id } ] }}"
  loop: "{{ access_control | product (access_control_id)| list }}"
```

But I only get a dictionary with access_ids:

```
    "combined_access_control": [
        {
            "access_id": "a01"
        },
        {
            "access_id": "a06"
        },
        {
            "access_id": "a01"
        },
        {
            "access_id": "a06"
        },
        {
            "access_id": "a01"
        },
        {
            "access_id": "a06"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to combine the dict from the lists, and append it to a list, like this:

```
    - name: Combine variables into one dict
      set_fact:
         combined_access_control: "{{ combined_access_control | default([]) + [ [] | combine (item.0) | combine ({ 'access_id': item.1.access_id }) ]}}"
      loop: "{{ access_control | product (access_control_id) | list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @sadok-f.  I had to add '| list' filter in the loop statement so that it would work properly, but having corrected that, it works.